# Using cssSandpaper with jQuery

Tags: jquery, rotatetransform

I'm trying to do something as the following code with `-sand-transform` from the the cssSandpaper:

```
$('#obj').css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(45deg)');
$('#obj').css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(45deg)');
```

This is what I'm trying but it doesn't work.

```
$('#obj').css('-sand-transform', 'rotate(45deg)');
```

It's possible to do something like that? It seems that only works if you declare it before in the CSS. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just changing the CSS property doesn't work, because `-sand-transform` is not a native CSS property. You must use the library methods to apply the transformation.

```
cssSandpaper.setTransform( $('#obj')[0], "rotate(45deg)" );
```

Comment: Thanks! It's possible to do the same with -sand-transform-origin ?